# Wicket "no application attached" when trying to access Hibernate entities

Tags: hibernate, wicket, jax-rs

I have just started working on an existing Wicket application that uses Hibernate. I am adding a RESTful interface to the Hibernate data (in the same web app) using JAX-RS. The JAX-RS servlets don't talk to Wicket at all---they create Hibernate sessions independently.

I have a class, `User`, that is defined as a Hibernate entity (that is also JAXB marshallable) using classes from `net.databinder.auth.data`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements DataUser {
```

Everything was working fine, until I tried to add setting the password (`BasicPassword` is an embeddable `net.databinder.auth.data` type) to my RESTful interface (until now, I was ignoring the password property):

```
@XmlTransient
public void setPassword(BasicPassword password) {
  this.password = password;
}

@XmlElement
public void setPassword(String password) {
  setPassword(new BasicPassword(password));
}
```

Suddenly, when Apache CXF-JAXRS + Jackson + JAXB tries to ummarshall my incoming JSON user object in an HTTP PUT, it calls `user.setPassword("...")` and I get the following error:

```
WARN  - ApplicationExceptionMapper - WebApplicationException has been caught : There is no application attached to current thread "http-bio-8080"-exec-5 (through reference chain: com.example.entity.User["password"])
```

Whoa---where did Wicket come in? Apache CXF-JAXRS should be invoking the Jackson provider, which uses the JAXB annotations to unmarshal my incoming user specification, creating an unbound Hibernate `User` object, right? It tries to set the password with a string, and the convenience method turns the string into a `BasicPassword` instance. None of this, as far as I can see, has anything to do with Wicket.

Why is Wicket even involved here? I don't want or need Wicket at this point---I just need to create a new detached Hibernate object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BasicPassword`](https://github.com/n8han/Databinder-for-Wicket/blob/master/databinder-auth-components-hib/src/main/java/net/databinder/auth/data/hib/BasicPassword.java) requires access to authorization settings of Wicket application in order to compute password hash. I guess you need to pass these requests through `WicketFilter` as well.

Comment: Oh, now I'm seeing the nasty access to the Wicket application in `BasicPassword.change()`. Arg. Excellent example of how _not_ to make some obscure dependency deep in the code. So, how do I route CXF JAX-RS requests through `WicketFilter` just to get the application set, but then have those request pass on on CXF?

Comment: @Garret: You can use `<filter-mapping>` with `<servlet-name>` inside it to apply filter to requests going to CXF servlet. Though I'm not quite familiar with Wicket and I'm not sure whether it's correct to combine `WicketFilter` with the rest of your Wicket application this way.

Comment: Yeah, that's the big worry. As far as I can tell, it either goes to Wicket, or it doesn't. Maybe I'll have to rewrite the whole `BasicPassword` class.

Comment: Try this: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/servlet/WicketSessionFilter.html

Comment: @tetsuo: I looked at the source code of `WicketSessionFilter`, and I see where it sets the session in a threadlocal, but I couldn't find where it sets the Wicket application via `Application.set()`.

Comment: @garret-wilson in 1.5 the `ThreadLocal` is not held by `Application` itself, but by [`ThreadContext`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ThreadContext.html), which is called from `WicketSessionFilter.bindApplication()`

Comment: @tetsuo: One of us doesn't understand. It could be me. :) Basically, the code in question requires that the current Wicket application be set so that it can retrieve it using `Application.get()`. Does `WicketSessionFilter` do whatever initialization needed to allow the application to be retrieved using `Application.get()`? (Sorry, I'm not by the code right now---I'll have to look later.)

Comment: Look at the [`Application` class source](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=wicket.git;a=blob_plain;f=wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Application.java;hb=HEAD). There is no `set()` method anymore. Instead, the application instance is held in `ThreadContext`, which is initialized by `WicketFilter` as well by `WicketSessionFilter`. I'm not sure if this will work in your case (I didn't test it), but by looking at the code, it seems to do what you need. It will prepare the Wicket environment (ThreadLocal singletons) for non-Wicket requests (given they are mapped to the filter)